# How to sort this Solr query by distance?

Tags: search, indexing, solr, lucene

I am querying results like this:

```
?q=*&wt=json&rows=1000&fq={!geofilt%20pt=36.722484,-4.371908%20sfield=location%20d=50}
```

This is using the `geofilt` function to find all results within 50km of a given point. But the results are returning in a strange order. I want to sort them by proximity to the given point, ascending. How can I add that to the above query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd bet you rather need to apply additional sorting param which is described here: [Spatial Search](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Spatial+Search#SpatialSearch-geodist).

So in your case it would look like:

```
?q=*&wt=json&rows=1000&fq={!geofilt%20pt=36.722484,-4.371908%20sfield=location%20d=50}&sort=geodist()+asc
```

Comment: No, returns this error: `"error":{"msg":"sort param could not be parsed as a query, and is not a field that exists in the index: geodist()","code":400}`

Comment: Which Solr version are you using?

Comment: We are using 5.4

Comment: I think what might be the case is using global parameters instead of local, like this: `&fq={!geofilt}&pt=36.722484,-4.371908&sfield=location&d=50&sort=geodist()+asc`. Could you please check it on your end?

Comment: Well, that doesn't return an error, but `asc` / `dsc` in that query return the exact same order. So it doesn't seem to be sorting.

Comment: I've been doing some follow up on that. It turns out that you should pay attention to url-encoding. Particularly I was missing `{!geofilt}` to be encoded as `%7B!geofilt%7D`. Just for your reference - I've set-up small project on that here: https://github.com/pvasilyev/stackoverflow/commit/fe9ad87831081af54a81dd3c3696b8d5868bf52d

Answer (score 0):

If the values you're getting isn't a field value, but the results of, say, a calculation (i.e. dynamically generated values, such as the distance between points) then you can sort the output of a function. Have a look at this link:

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#Sort_By_Function